# New checkbox in custom post type widget isn't saving data

Tags: custom-post-types

I created a custom post type to add customer testimonials.  However the histdesig (historical designation) field, a checkbox, is not updating when I check it. Code to create the CPT is below.

I did change it from a 'text' type to a 'checkbox' type, because midway through I realized that I would only have one historical designation.  Before changing it, I wiped the data from that field.  However, I suspect that something is up with mysql. Is that likely? What should I do to remedy it?

```
function create_posttype() {
  $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __('Testimonials'),
      'singular_name' => __('Testimonials'),
      'all_items' => __('All Testimonials'),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New Testimonial'),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit Testimonial'),
      'view_item' => __('View Testimonial')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'testimonials'),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'menu_position' => 80,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-status'
    );
  register_post_type('testimonials', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype');

function my_add_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box( 'testimonial-details', 'Testimonial Details', 'my_testimonials_cb', 'testimonials', 'normal', 'default');
}
function my_testimonials_cb($post){
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $client_name = isset( $values['client_name'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['client_name'][0] ) : "";
    $neighborhood = isset( $values['neighborhood'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['neighborhood'][0] ) : "";
    $jobtype = isset( $values['jobtype'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['jobtype'][0] ) : "";
    $builtin = isset( $values['builtin'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['builtin'][0] ) : "";
    $architect = isset( $values['architect'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['architect'][0] ) : "";
    $histdesig = isset( $values['histdesig'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['histdesig'][0] ) : "";

    wp_nonce_field( 'testimonial_details_nonce_action', 'testimonial_details_nonce' );
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<label>Client Name</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:9px; margin-bottom:10px;" value="'. $client_name .'" /><br/>';
    $html .= '<label>Neighborhood</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="neighborhood" id="neighborhood" style="margin-left:25px; margin-bottom:15px;" value="'. $neighborhood .'" /><br/>';
    $html .= '<label>Job type</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="jobtype" id="jobtype" style="margin-left:25px; margin-bottom:15px;" value="'. $jobtype .'" /><br/>';
    $html .= '<label>Built in</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="builtin" id="builtin" style="margin-left:25px; margin-bottom:15px;" value="'. $builtin .'" /><br/>';
    $html .= '<label>Architect</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="architect" id="architect" style="margin-left:25px; margin-bottom:15px;" value="'. $architect .'" /><br/>';
    $html .= '<label>Historic Designation</label>';
    $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="histdesig" id="histdesig" style="margin-left:25px; margin-bottom:15px;" value="'. $histdesig .'" />';
    echo $html;
}
function my_save_meta_box($post_id){
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['testimonial_details_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['testimonial_details_nonce'], 'testimonial_details_nonce_action' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    if(isset( $_POST['client_name'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'client_name', $_POST['client_name']);

    if(isset( $_POST['neighborhood'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'neighborhood', $_POST['neighborhood']);

    if(isset( $_POST['jobtype'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'jobtype', $_POST['jobtype']);

    if(isset( $_POST['builtin'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'builtin', $_POST['builtin']);

    if(isset( $_POST['architect'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'architect', $_POST['architect']);

    if(isset( $_POST['histdesig'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'histdesig', $_POST['histdesig']);
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_meta_box' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_meta_box' );
```